# Running PDFTron in a separate AppDomain: "Cannot pass a GCHandle across AppDomains"

Tags: c#, appdomain, pdftron

PDFTron seems not to be able to handle more than one AppDomain. When running PDFTron from a separate AppDomain, the application crashes with an unhandled exception ("Cannot pass a GCHandle across AppDomains").

```
   bei System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.InternalCheckDomain(IntPtr handle)
   bei System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.FromIntPtr(IntPtr value)
   bei gcroot<pdftron::PDF::PDFViewWPF ^>.->(gcroot<pdftron::PDF::PDFViewWPF ^>* )
   bei pdftron.PDF.detail.DeluxeCreateTile(Void* data, SByte* buffer, UInt32 width, UInt32 height, UInt32 stride, UInt32 page_num, UInt64 x_page_loc, UInt64 y_page_loc, UInt32 zoomed_page_width, UInt32 zoomed_page_height, UInt32 tile_id, UInt32 x_in_page, UInt32 y_in_page, Int32 canvas_id, Int32 remaining_tiles, Int32 tile_type, Int32 sequenceNum)
```

While searching for a solution I found a thread in the Google Groups forum which was created in 2011. A user got the same exception in an outlook plugin he was working on. According to the topic the issue has been known to the PDFTron support and also was fixed in one of the WinForms-based controls. You can find the discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pdfnet-sdk/DGki3Fj2_FU

Do I have to consider something or is PDFTron simply not able to run in this environment?

This is the code from the example I used to reproduce the issue:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="RunningPdfTronUsingMultipleAppDomains.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RunningPdfTronUsingMultipleAppDomains"
        xmlns:pdf="clr-namespace:pdftron.PDF;assembly=PDFNet"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <pdf:PDFViewWPF x:Name="PDFView"/>
        <Button Panel.ZIndex="100" Height="20" Width="110" Content="Create AppDomain" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PDFDoc document = new PDFDoc("SampleDocument.pdf");
        PDFView.SetDoc(document);
    }

        private void Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MainWindow));
            appDomain.Load(assembly.GetName());
            Proxy proxy = (Proxy)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().FullName, typeof(Proxy).FullName);
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart((o) => proxy.Invoke())) { ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA };
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
```

**Proxy.cs**

```
  public class Proxy : MarshalByRefObject
        {
            public void Invoke()
            {
                try
                {
                    App app = new App();
                    app.Run(new MainWindow());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I dont know pdftron in paticular, but according to the error message you just have to ensure that you dont pass a GCHandle across the appdomain boundary. Are you required to do so?

Comment: I am assuming that PDFTron is doing so. The exception originates from the method "DeluxeCreateTile" which is part of the PDFNet SDK.

Comment: I assume you create the seperate AppDomain. Then it should be your job to not move a pdftron related object across the domain. Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I just provided the code necessary for reproducing this issue. I am not aware, that it is my code which is moving the pdftron related object across the domain. What object should that be?

Comment: I can not run the code at the moment, maybe someone other can. Does the same happen in the most minimalistic scenario (no ui, no thread)?

Comment: At least I have to bring the UI into play to receive this error. It occurs only if the PDF document is associated with the viewer control (PDFView.SetDoc(document).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed report. "Do I have to consider something or is PDFTron simply not able to run in this environment?" What environment are you running under? The issue you referred to in the Google Group was a user instantiating PDFViewCtrl in an Outlook plugin, which was isolated in a different AppDomain for security. Are you also creating an MS Office plugin?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. By referring to my specific environment, I mean that the PDFViewWPF is used in a separate app domain. We are not developing an Outlook plugin, but we are also using separate app domains for isolation purposes. To me it seemed that it is the same issue the user from the Google group was faced with.

Comment: Hey Ryan, i would appreciate an answer :-)

Comment: We are currently investigating this issue. In the meantime, it would be great to know why isolating the PDFViewWPF document viewing is important?

Comment: Hey Ryan. Isolating the PDFViewWPF viewing ist not important for us. Indeed it is a side effect of using multiple application domains for the purpose of having an isolation boundary for security reasons and in order to be able to unload assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

FYI: PDFTron WPF 6.8 (slated for January) will include support for multiple/separate AppDomains